# how to use operators as variables

Tags: php, variables, operators

I have a variable $operator which has the value of '+', or '-'. I also have two numbers as variables $no1, $no2. How do I add or subtract these variables without using if statements:

e.g. if $no1 = 7 and $no2 = 14 and $operator = +; I want

```
$answer = $no1 $operator $no2
```

to become
7 + 14; or essentially $answer has the value of 21. How is this done?

Comment: what about `eval($no1.$operator.$no2);` ?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '14' (T_LNUMBER) in /ajax-operator.php(7) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: use this : `eval('echo '.$no1.$operator.$no2.';');`

Comment: Instead of $no1 $operator $no2 why don't you try writing $operator($no1, $no2) and define your operators as anonymous functions?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is writing a function like this:

```
function calculate($varOne, $operator, $varTwo) {
    switch($operator) {
        case '+':
            $result = $varOne + $varTwo;
            break;
        case '-':
            $result = $varOne - $varTwo;
            break;
        default:
            $result = 0;
            break;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Here you can add different calculations in the switch statement based on the value of the $op variable. You could add multiplication or division for example.

Then you could use the function like this:

```
$result = calculate(7, '+', 14);
echo($result);
```

Would yield:

```
21
```

With $result holding 21 also.

Of course you could add things like checking for integers or floats in the $varOne and $varTwo variables, but I'll leave it up to you to expand this as you wish.